Question about defect subgroups
Let $G$ be a finite group over an algebraically closed field $\Bbbk$ of characteristic $p>0$.  Let $b$ be a block of $G$.  Then the a defect subgroup $D$ of $b$ is one for which every module in $b$ is relatively projective over $D$.
My question is: to check if every module in $b$ is relatively projective over $b$, is it enough to check it for all simple modules in $b$?
For example, if $b$ is the principal block, then the answer is yes, because if the trivial module is relatively projective over $D$, then every $G$-module is using the monoidal structure.

(In the standard algebraically closed case) the answer is yes.
It is true that every $p$-block $B$ of defect $d$ of a finite group $G$ contains a simple module $S$  whose dimension is divisible by the exact $p$-power $p^{a-d}$, where $p^{a}$ is the order of a Sylow $p$-subgroup of  $G$.
This is a consequence of a the theorem of R.Brauer, which states that the exact power of $p$ dividing the dimension of $B$ is $p^{2a-d}$, ( while the dimension of $B$ is the sum over all simples in $B$ of dim(S)dimP(S), where P(S) is the projective cover of $S$).
Since dim(P(S)) is always divisible by $p^{a}$,  and dim(S) is always divisible  by $p^{a-d}$, there must be at least one simple module $S$ in $B$ with dim(S)  not divisible by $p^{a-d+1}$.
This implies the statement you want in terms of relative projectivity. In terms of Vertices and sources, it says that every block $B$ contains a simple module whose vertex is the defect group of the block.

Dear Geoff, thank you so much for your quick answer.  Please tell me if I follow: are you saying that if S is the "special" simple module of dimension not divisible by $p^{a-d+1}$, and it is rel. proj. over a $p$-subgroup $D$ of order $p^d$, then $D$ must (clearly) be the vertex of $S$, and thus must be the defect subgroup

Yes, that is more or less what I am saying at the end. That $S$ can't  be relatively projective with respect to any proper subgroup of the defect group (but is of course relative projective with respect to the defect group).

There is a more "modern" proof by J.A.. Green in a paper where he proves it using the fact that $B$ is an indecomposable trivial source  $G \times G$-module whose vertex is the diagonal subgroup of  $D \times D.$ I think at least one of the proofs will be in Navarro's book on Characters and Blocks.

Thank you!  Sorry for deleting my previous comment, I ended up finding a reference.  But I think yours is much better!
